# Effective Resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance

For the combination of the resistors, shown in the figure. Calculate the equivalent resistance between A and B, please help me to find the answer of this complicated question this is a question from an easy part but, I don't know how to solve this.

[image: For the combination of the resistors, shown in the figure. Calculate the equivalent resistance between A and B, please help me to find the answer of this complicated question this is a question from an easy part but, I don't KNOW TO SOLVE THIS]

Comment: Start from the B end, and try to replace two resistors by an equivalent one. Then repeat until finished. It should not be hard: "resistance is futile".

Comment: It is not always that easy. Sometimes you have to write equations, because you cannot isolate pairs of resistors.

Answer (score 1):

## *This is a homework(-like) question so I may not give a full answer.*

Let $\alpha$ be the bottom resistor with 100 omega resistance.
Let $\beta$ be the middle resistor with 100 omega resistance.
Let $\gamma$ be the top resistor with 100 omega resistance.
Let $\delta$ be the resistor with 25 omega resistance.
Let $\varepsilon$ be the resistor with  120 omega resistance.
Let $\zeta$ be the resistor with     40 omega resistance.

If you see the resistors               $\alpha$ and $\delta$, they are in parallel, so they add up to     a resistance     given by $\frac1R=\frac1{R_1}+\frac1{R_2}$.       Let's call this "parallel addition".

This added up resistance is in series, with    resistor $\beta$, so they're total resistance is merely their sum.       Let's call this "serial addition".

This resistance is to be parallelly added to the resistor $\varepsilon$, which can be serially added to the resistor $\gamma$ and so on.

The formulas I mentioned can be obtained from any standard       introductory physics or such textbook.               My personal favourite is Jewett and Serway  *Physics for Scientists and Engineers with Modern Physics*.

Comment: If answering hardware problems isn't allowed; why did YOU answer it.   You give an answer that is specific to this network; not all networks.  And it is obvious, from the specific numbers in the question, that the author's full intent was for it to be solved, by inspection exactly as I explained to the "OP", as you call him/er.  If it was my question on an exam paper, I would dock the student points for using the laborious method you describe; in fact I have done precisely that, for a similar network problem that had an obvious answer by inspection, that I asked on an exam paper.

Comment: Well Dimension 10, you really are touchy with your "ranting" citations. And absolutely nowhere or at any time, did I mention anybody asking or answering questions in another language (besides English) .   What I DID say, was that many posters do not write in the English language.   English has a robust grammar, and well defined words.  Misuse of those conveys misinformation.   If somebody writes " hw " instead of homework, and also writes " OP "  instead of original poster, they are not writing in English.      And I've got children older than you, so don't get uppity with me.